# Function that removes 10's from an array, replaces 10's with 0's. Shifts all remaining elements to start of array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, nested-loops

Write a function that removes all the 10's from an array of n integers. The remaining elements should be shifted left towards the start of the array as required, and the "empty" spaces at the end of the array should be set to 0, So far we have code is not functioning properly when we run sput.h test harness

```
void without_tens(int *arr, int n) {
    int i = 0; 
    for (int j = 0; arr[j] % 10 == 0 && j < n; j++) {
        arr[j] = 0;
        i = j; 
        while (i < n && arr[i] % 10 != 0 && arr[i + 1] != 0) {
            arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
            break;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: OK, so do you have a question here?

Comment: Code isn't functioning properly when we run the sput.h test harness there is an issue.

Comment: You do not need two nested loops. Use one loop (`i`) and a destination index (`j`), to copy values that are not 10 to the destination. When the loop ends, fill the array elements from `j` to `i-1` with `0`.

Comment: Would you mind telling us *the issue*?

Comment: @WeatherVane - very nice answer, gave him the solution but not the code :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways... that's one of them.

```
void remove_tens(int *arr, int len )
{
    int i = 0, n = 0;

    // Skip numbers 10 from de copy 
    for( i = 0 ; i < len ; i++ )
        arr[i] != 10 ? arr[n++] = arr[i] : arr[n] = 0;

    // Fill de array with 0 
    for( i = n ; i < len ; i++ )
        arr[i] = 0;
}
```

**First one**: don't copy 10 numbers, skip them

I will use `n` as an index of each non 10 number correctly copied to the array.

```
// Skip numbers 10 from de copy 
for( i = 0 ; i < len ; i++ )
     arr[i] != 10 ? arr[n++] = arr[i] : arr[n] = 0;
```

That for means... If the current element is different of 10 (`arr[i] != 10`), copy that element (`arr[i]`) to the result array and move one (`arr[n++] = arr[i]`), if not, don't move and don't copy anything (`arr[n] = 0`).

**Second one**: fill the *spaces* with 0's

Starting at n (`for( i = n...`), fill with 0's (`arr[i] = 0;`).

Code and an example on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb850c16ee700312)

```
void remove_tens(int *arr, int len )
{
    int i = 0, n = 0;

    // Skip numbers 10 from de copy 
    for( i = 0 ; i < len ; i++ )
        arr[i] != 10 ? arr[n++] = arr[i] : arr[n] = 0;

    // Fill the array with 0 
    for( i = n ; i < len ; i++ )
        arr[i] = 0;
}


int main ()
{
    int numbers[5];
    int i = 0;

    numbers[0] = 4;
    numbers[1] = 5;
    numbers[2] = 10;
    numbers[3] = 1;
    numbers[4] = 10;

    remove_tens(numbers, 5);

    // Printing the result    
    for( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
        printf("%d", numbers[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aghhh... you are right... :S